# Having problems using (>= & <=) while trying to operate/filter a data frame created by a groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I'm trying to remove outliers from my dataset. This is real estate data, so I used a groupby to group by 'Zone/Area' (on the code it actually says 'Zona') and I calculated the IQR with the price per 'Zone/Area', but now that I'm trying to use ">= & <=" to filter out the outliers I get a TypeError.

Here's my code.

First I just created a new data frame with only the "Zone" and "Price" and used box plots to check if there were outliers.

```
#Create a new dataframe with only "Precio USD" & "Zona"
gt_venta_precio_zona = gt_venta[['Precio USD','Zona']]
#Group by "Zona"
grp = gt_venta_precio_zona.groupby('Zona')
#Iterate through the groups to get the keys (titles) of each "Zona" and plot the results
for key in grp.groups.keys():
    grp.get_group(key).plot.box(title=key)
```

After noticing many outliers by "Zone", I calculated the IQR and tried to use that to filter out the outliers by "Zone", here's the code.

```
Q1 = grp['Precio USD'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = grp['Precio USD'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
#Let's reshape the quartiles to be able to operate them
Q1 = Q1.values.reshape(-1,1)
Q3 = Q3.values.reshape(-1,1)
IQR = IQR.values.reshape(-1,1)
print(Q1.shape, Q3.shape, IQR.shape)
```

Everything was running smoothly until I tried to filter my data frame based on that data with this code:

```
#Let's filter the dataset based on the IQR * +- 1.5
filter = (grp['Precio USD'] >= Q1 - 1.5 * IQR) & (grp['Precio USD'] <= Q3 + 1.5 *IQR)
grp.loc[filter]
```

I get the following traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-09dffe5671dd> in <module>
      9 
     10 #Let's filter the dataset based on the IQR * +- 1.5
---> 11 filter = (grp['Precio USD'] >= Q1 - 1.5 * IQR) & (grp['Precio USD'] <= Q3 + 1.5 *IQR)
     12 grp.loc[filter]

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

I reviewed the dtype of all of the values "Price" under each "Zone" and they are all floats, the same goes for the quantiles and IQR.

I tried converting everything into Int's but I couldn't do that either since I'm using a groupby. So I'm kind of stuck here.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

PS. Here's my full code (so far):

```
# Let's start by loading the dataset

# In[1]:


#Import the necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

# Read the CSV file into a DataFrame: df
gt_df = pd.read_csv('RE_Data_GT.csv')
gt_df.tail()


# Let's do some simple statistical analysis to understand the variables we have and their behaviour a little better.

# In[2]:


#Fill in NaN's with the man of the column on the "Banos" column
gt_df['Banos'] = gt_df['Banos'].fillna(gt_df['Banos'].mean())
gt_df.info()


# In[3]:


gt_df.describe()


# From the table above we can see that a few of the columns have data very spread out (high standard deviation), this is not necessarily bad, because we know the dataset we understand that this could be caused by the two types of listings ('Venta' y 'Alquiler'), it makes sense to have variance if we look at prices by rent and sales at the same time. 
# 
# Now let's move to one of the most exciting parts, which is some exploratory data analysis (EDA). But before we do that, I think that with the information above it would make sense to have two different dataframes one for rentals and other for home sales. 

# In[4]:


gt_alquiler = gt_df[gt_df['Tipo de listing'] == 'Alquiler']
gt_venta = gt_df[gt_df['Tipo de listing'] == 'Venta']
gt_alquiler.info()
gt_venta.info()


# Excellent, it seems like we have 2128 data points for 'Alquiler'(rental) and 3004 for 'Venta' (sales). Now that we have our 2 dataframes, we can actually start to do some EDA, we'll start by looking at home sales (Tipo de listing =='Venta').

# In[5]:


_ = gt_venta['Precio USD'].plot.hist(title = 'Distribucion de Precios de Venta', colormap='Pastel2')
_ = plt.xlabel('Price in USD')


# In[6]:


#Declare a function to compute the ECDF of an array
def ecdf(data):
    """Compute ECDF for a one-dimensional array of measurements."""
    # Number of data points: n
    n = len(data)

    # x-data for the ECDF: x
    x = np.sort(data)

    # y-data for the ECDF: y
    y = np.arange(1, len(data)+1) / n

    return x, y


# In[7]:


#Create Variable to pass to the ECDF function
gt_venta_precio = gt_venta['Precio USD']

#Compute ECDF for
x, y = ecdf(gt_venta_precio)

# Generate plot
_ = plt.plot(x, y, marker='.', linestyle='none')

# Add title and label the axes
_ = plt.title('ECDF de Precio en USD')
_ = plt.xlabel('Precio en USD')
_ = plt.ylabel('ECDF')

# Display the plot
plt.show()


# Apparently there are a few outliers that require our attention. To better understand these points, it's better if we group them by a 'zona' (zona/area) to see which listing has such a high price. 
# 
# Let's start to understand the specific outliers by grouping the listings by "Zona" and then using a box plot for each to review each in more detail.

# In[8]:


#Create a new dataframe with only "Precio USD" & "Zona"
gt_venta_precio_zona = gt_venta[['Precio USD','Zona']]
#Group by "Zona"
grp = gt_venta_precio_zona.groupby('Zona')
#Iterate through the groups to get the keys (titles) of each "Zona" and plot the results
for key in grp.groups.keys():
    grp.get_group(key).plot.box(title=key)


# In[14]:


Q1 = grp['Precio USD'].quantile(0.25)
Q3 = grp['Precio USD'].quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
#Let's reshape the quartiles to be able to operate them
Q1 = Q1.values.reshape(-1,1)
Q3 = Q3.values.reshape(-1,1)
IQR = IQR.values.reshape(-1,1)
print(Q1.shape, Q3.shape, IQR.shape)

#Let's filter the dataset based on the IQR * +- 1.5
filter = (grp['Precio USD'] >= (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) & (grp['Precio USD'] <= (Q3 + 1.5 *IQR))
grp.loc[filter]
```

Dataset can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JXDm9iYem4DlMoIjx4f7yWBuwjaLRThe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It might be an issue with parentheses. Can you try putting the part after `<=` in parentheses? If that doesn’t work, we’re probably going to need enough of your code and data to run the program. See: [mcve]. Also, don’t use `.values`.

Comment: I think you can iterate over the groups using `for key, val in groupby():` instead of iterating over the keys and then accessing the values.

Comment: Forgot to link this useful article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Is one of the values a string? If it's a number use int(value)

Comment: Hi @AlexanderCécile, thank you so much for responding. Is there a specific reason as to why I shouldn't use ".values"? I used it because the .reshape method on the Q variables didn't work. So I read on another post that I had to use .values and it worked... Also, I've added my full code to the post! Again, thank you so much for the support.

Comment: @EduardoMartinez Because the docs say so :p That’s really the only explanation I can provide at the moment, I have yet to investigate why that is the case. Can you include your data in a way that is easy to use, even if it’s only part of it? The goal is for anyone to be able to copy/paste a few things and have your program running in a matter of minutes.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderCécile, thanks for the response. I'll take a deeper look at the document. Also, I just added a link to the dataset on the post... thank you so much for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is useful, I was able to achieve my goal of removing outliers with the following function:

```
def remove_outliers(df, column):
    "This function takes in a dataframe and removes the outliers using the values of the specified column"
    #Use the describe() method to identify the statistics of interest
    describe = df[column].describe()

    #Create a dictionary for each of the values from the column of interest
    describe_dict = {"count":0,"mean":1,"std":2,"min":3,"25":4,"50":5,"75":6,"max":7}

    #Extract quartiles (Q1, Q3)
    Q1 = describe[describe_dict['25']]
    Q3 = describe[describe_dict['75']]

    #Caculate IQR
    IQR = Q3-Q1

    #Define bounds
    lb = Q1-1.5*IQR
    ub = Q3+1.5*IQR
    print("(IQR = {})A point outside of the following range can be considered an outlier: ({},{})".format(IQR,lb,ub))

    calc_df = df[(df[column] < lb) | (df[column] > ub)]
    print("The number of outliers that will be removed out of {} observations are {}.".format(df[column].size,len(calc_df[column])))

    #remove the outliers from the dataframe
    no_outliers = df[~df[column].isin(calc_df[column])]
    return no_outliers
```

You just need to pass it a data frame and specify the column that you want to use as a base to identify and remove the outliers. On my github you can find a notebook with a quick tutorial:

https://github.com/omartinez182/web-apps/blob/master/Remove%20Outliers.ipynb